# How to read a formatted ASCII STL file with numbers and characters of varying length using Fortran?

Tags: arrays, string, parsing, fortran, character

I'm trying to read a STL file with varying format. A STL file in a
 generic format consists of

> ```
>    solid solid_name
>       facet normal n1 n2 n3 (the triangles normal vector)
>          outerloop         (one of the markers I want to read)
>             v1          x1 y1 z1
>             v2          x2 y2 z2       (three vertex of the triangle/facet)    
>             v3          x3 y3 z3
>          endloop
>         end facet
>     endsolid
> ```

The idea is to loop throughout the solid, facet and vertex and read the information. My problem is that I'm trying to read files with different formats: For example, in one of them, I have for the first facet:

```
>solid Peca2
>   facet normal 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
>      outer loop
>         vertex 1.250000e+02 7.500000e+01 1.000000e+02
>         vertex 1.250000e+02 2.500000e+01 1.000000e+02
>         vertex 1.250000e+02 7.500000e+01 5.000000e+01
>      endloop
and so on.
```

My problem is that since the values of each vertex component may vary in magnitude, I'm having trouble finding the correct format to read this information. I've tried exponential, floating point and even strings, but the data my code is reading from the file is complete nonsensical, such as:

```
 solid Peca2

   facet normal 1.000000e+00
  0.000000e+0
 0 0.000000e+00

   outer loop

    vertex 1.250000e+
```

After I've done reading the data, I'm supposed to write the same data on a new STL file. I've tried both unformatted and formatted reading and writing, but nothing seems to work. The only effect I've observed is the written data shifting positions from one line to the other, as shown in the last figure.

So, I have some questions:

1) How can I write a generic STL reader that reads any file, in any format, without it being prespecified? Is it even possible?

2) How can I read floating point and exponential data from a file that has varying lenght, as can be observed in the line

```
1.250000e+02 7.500000e+01 5.000000e+01
```

3) I tried reading the information on every line as a allocatable character string, and was apparently successful, but when I print the string to check it's content, the output is also chaotic, like before:

```
facet n
    ormal 1.000000e+00 0
      .000000e+00 0.000000
   e+00
```

I've tried pretty much every read command in the following forms, varying the width and the digits of the format in many, many combinations, but nothing has worked properly.

```
read(iunit, fmt= '(a, G8.6, G8.6, G8.6)', iostat=ios) vertex, vertices(1,k), vertices(1,k+1), vertices(1,k+2)
read(iunit, fmt= '(a, F2.0, E2.0, E2.0)', iostat=ios) vertex, vertices(1,k), vertices(1,k+1), vertices(1,k+2)
read(iunit, fmt= '(a, E10.6, E10.6, E10.6)', iostat=ios) vertex, vertices(1,k), vertices(1,k+1), vertices(1,k+2)
```

Can anybody please help me dealing with these formatting questions? Any help is very appreciated, as I've been struggling with these problem for quite a long time.

Comment: Fortran fixed column Format is not well suited for this, the columns ate not fixed. You need  a real parser. However, wby are you reinventing a wheel? There are libraries for STL.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: Just use a format free read which solves your problem with the width of the numbers. On too of that check your iostat to distinguish between formats.

Comment: You need to write a parser for this.  I have removed STL because it means the C++ standard template library.

Comment: @ Vladimir F, I've been looking for these libraries for quite a while, but I never found anything that works. Would you by any chance know a website where I can find reliable Fortran code to read any ASCII STL file? Thanks.

Comment: @ kvantour, I've tried reading without any formats, but I'm still having trouble because the program is not reading the entire line. For example, I've tried using a character array 'line' to read the information on each line, as follows:                                                                                          do i=1,3

      len_line=5
      allocate(character(len=len_line) :: line(4))
      read(iunit, iostat=ios) line
      print*, line
      write(iunit2) line(2), line(3), line(4)
      deallocate(line)

    end do

Comment: @ kvantour, I've tried reading without any formats, but I'm still having trouble because the program is not reading the entire line. For example, I've tried using a character array 'line' to read the information on each line, as follows:                                                                                          
          len_line=5
          allocate(character(len=len_line) :: line(4))
          read(iunit, iostat=ios) line
          print*, line
          write(iunit2) line(2), line(3), line(4)
          deallocate(line)